# One item shows up the render, but another doesn't

Tags: rendering

I'm making a scene with the *Death Star* and a *TIE fighter* flies by it. But the TIE fighter won't render. What do I do?

Comment: Please provide us with some more information regarding you're scene as this question is far to broad to answer.

Comment: Blender has no filters for TIE fighters or any other StarWars branded objects... If we know nothing about your scene or settings is hard to help you. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question and add more information.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry. I have not yet put the texture on the TIE fighter, but I did put the texture on the sphere that I made the Death Star into. The TIE fighter that I created myself will not show up when I render it.

Comment: @Skyler Hi. If you need to add more information to your question please use the [edit] link below it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your fighter is in another layer. If it is then take it to the same layer where is the death star. This should help. If u  want to skip this then you can select both layers and then render.